# How to make LazyColumn scrollable in ConstraintLayout in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I created a ConstraintLayout and it contains a LazyColumn. However, when the elements don't fit in the screen, I cannot scroll through the column. How can I fix this?

I've tried adding `state = rememberLazyListState()` but it did not work.

```kotlin
ConstraintLayout(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(padding)) 
{
    val (text, btns, list) = createRefs()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(text) { top.linkTo(parent.top); bottom.linkTo(btns.bottom) }
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(50.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) { /* Composables */ }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(btns) { top.linkTo(text.bottom) }
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) { /* Composables */ }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(list) { top.linkTo(btns.bottom) }
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(25.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        // test
        Text(text = "List:", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, fontSize = 25.sp)
        LazyColumn( state = rememberLazyListState(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            items(monomios.keys.toTypedArray()) {
                Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(25.dp).background(color = Color.Red)) {
                    Text(text = (it).toString())
                    Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.cruz), contentDescription = "")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable scrolling for a `LazyColumn` inside a `ConstraintLayout`, you need to ensure that the `LazyColumn` has enough height to accommodate its content and that it's placed within a scrollable container.